# How to prevent Nginx rewrite rule from encoding "&" in request

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Following request:

`/service/data/packet/{|79A90E010D021211120511300003E40000000000000D900~5}&param1=1234&param2=12.64&param3=4&param4=6`

needs to be translated and routed to:

`/path/to/file?pkt={|79A90E010D021211120511300003E40000000000000D900~5}&param1=1234&param2=12.64&param3=4&param4=6`

I have tried the following solutions:

1. `rewrite /service/data/packet/?(.*)$ /path/to/file?pkt=$1? last;`

This seems to encode **&** to **%26** in the request, which breaks it.

2. I tried segregating the parameters and rewriting it to the routed url like:

`rewrite ^/service/data/packet/(.+)&param1=(.+)&param2=(.+)&param3=(.+)&param4=(.+) /path/to/file?pkt=$1&param1=$arg_param1&param2=$arg_param2&param3=$arg_param3&param4=$arg_param4;`

Nginx here does not seems to recognise `$args_<param-name>` and hence pass `pkt=&param1=&param2=&param3=&param4=` in request.

Is there a way to tell nginx not to encode the request before passing it in the first case? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was finally able to solve this problem. The second workaround seemed to work with some modifications as shown:

`"^/service/data/packet/(.+)&param1=(.+)&param2=(.+)&param3=(.+)&param4=(.+)$" "/path/to/file?pkt=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4&param4=$5?";`

1. Nginx will substitute the param variables based on the "capturing group", so, for all the request params, the regex has to be in a capturing group; i.e; enclosed inside "()". Then only it will be available as variables.
2. The automatic encoding issue can be taken care of by enclosing the rewrite rule inside double quotes as shown.

Since, in my case, the length of first two params are fixed, the rule can be modified to a more efficient form as:

`"^/service/data/packet/(.{52})&param1=(.{15})&param2=(.+)&param3=(.+)&param4=(.+)$" "/path/to/file?pkt=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3&param3=$4&param4=$5?";`